# Sorting Multiple ArrayLists Advice?

Tags: java

Hey there guys and gals.

Background:
I'm working on a high score program for homework that asks for 5 names and 5 scores. After the names with the corresponding scores are entered the program sorts the two ArrayLists by highest score. Finally it displays the names with their scores in sorted order.

Question:
I'm having the devil of a time trying to sort the ArrayLists , do you any advice on sorting ArrayLists ?

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment6
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList();

        initializeArrays(names, scores);
        //sortArrays(names, scores);
        displayArrays(names, scores);
    }

        public static void initializeArrays(ArrayList names, ArrayList scores)
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the name for score # " + (i+1) + ": ");
                names.add(in.next());
                System.out.println("Enter the score for score # " + (i+1) + ": ");
                scores.add(in.next());
            }
        }

        public static void sortArrays(ArrayList names, ArrayList scores)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                if(scores[i] < scores[i+1])
                {
                    Collections.swap(scores,a, b);
                    Collections.swap(names,a, b);

                }
            }
        }

        public static void displayArrays(ArrayList names, ArrayList scores)
        {
            System.out.println("Top Scorers: ");
            System.out.println(names);
            System.out.println(scores);
        }


}
```

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: Collections.swap() is a handy utility for your purposes! But what are `a` and `b`? They aren't defined anywhere and your compiler messages should be yelling as much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one object with fields: `name` and `score` with `implements Comparable`.
Then having **ONLY** one `ArrayList` use `Collections.sort(list);`

Comment: Why should anyone doing a basic homework assignment use Comparable?

Comment: @clwhisk Because it's simpler and better approach.

Comment: It's simpler to order the list oneself. Once you understand how to compare elements, it doesn't matter where you put that code, you can just accomplish sorting with it.

Comment: @clwhisk It's simpler to use what already exists and not to waste time for it.

Comment: Generally using a preexisting sort method is great, but quite the opposite and forbidden for beginner homework.

Comment: @clwhisk The method swap() from Collections is already used anyway in the original post.

Comment: That's conceptually a whole lot better than getting a magic wand that does everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap both score and name into one object and store it in a list.

```
class Result implements Comparable<Result>{

    private String name;

    private int score;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Result other) {
        return this.score - other.score;
    }

}
```

Now you can use `Collections.sort(List<Result>)` to sort them out based on the highest score.

Comment: Have you seen Alex's answer, why you have added duplication ?

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk At least it removes one layer of abstraction from that.

Answer (score 0):

ok, do you want to print something like that `A-{Bob, Alex, ...},` where Bob is a name and A is scope, you can do it  using one object as described by Alex, but if its home work I think your teacher want to see some comuter science data structure, in that case is [Associative_array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) will be better. You can implement it by your side or use java implementation. Java provide us Map [T, V] , and implementation, for your case is TreeMap, where T - is scope and V - is a List of the Name because a lot of people can have the same scope.
So, result structure will be like that

```
Map<String, List<String>> sortedScopes = new TreeMap<>();
```

and using :

```
List<String> names  = sortedScopes.get(scope);
if(names == null){
  names = new ArrayList<>();
sortedScopes.put(scope, names);
}

names.add(name)
```

---

In that solution you will have just a 2 methods initialize and display, 
Sorting by scope will execute on demand